# How to iterate data to different components/divs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

In react and redux, I am trying to iterate rss data from news websites to different components/divs. I am not really sure how to explain this

Basically I have a main container that has 3 rows of divs(components), and the structure of each divs is different. The first row of div has other 3 divs with same size, the second one has two, and the third one has one. [this is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJFk6.png)

I want to pass data to each div. For example, I have 10 data from api call, and I want the first row of divs to have 3 data(data 1,2,3) since it has 3 divs, the second row to have 2 data(data 4,5) and last row to have 1 data(data 6), then going back to the first row.

I tried to pass data from main container to 3 containers(divs), but it did not go the way that I wanted to.

My main container component looks like this:

```
render() {
 const news = this.props.news.map(data =>
  <div>
    <Container1  data={data} />
    <Container2  data={data} />
    <Container3  data={data} />
  </div>
);
 return (
  <div className="container">
     {news}
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use somthing like this :

```
export default class RowExt extends Component {
   state = {
   clearData : null
   };
  componentWillReceiveProps = (nextProps)=> {
    if (this.props.data !== nextProps.data) {
      this.setState({
        clearData: nextProps.data.slice(0, this.props.count)
      });
    }
  };
 }
```

and use like this in another render method:

```
render () {
return(
  <RowExt count={2}/>
)
}
```

or you can check index in `map` function and pass `count` props like this :

```
render () {

      return(

        <div className="container">
             {mapdata && mapdata.map((Row_data,index)=>{
              return(

                      <RowExt count={index == 0 ? 2 : index == 1 ? 1 :                     index == 1 ? 0 } data={Row_data}/>

               );
             })}
         </div>

     );
}
```